# Neo4J on EC2 AWS java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error — How to fix?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, neo4j

Neo4J 3.3.4 is running on EC2 t3.medium AWS instance with 2 vCPUs and 4Gb RAM. As it is launched through the AWS AMI Neo4J image it runs through `systemctl`.

Sometimes when the demand is too high it stalls and while there is no information in `debug.log` if I type in `systemctl status neo4j` I see the following error:

```
Jul 25 18:55:14 ip-x-x-x-x pre-neo4j.sh[5493]: Exception in thread "qtp1269774727-33" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I detect this sort of error and relaunch the database in that case?

Is it possible to avoid it at all by tweaking the settings in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.template` ?

I used both the default commented out and those below but this didn't really have any positive effect. How to fix that?

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1996m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1996m
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=1g
```

Comment: One of the first things to do would be to look at the *query* that is running at the time of the OOM error to see if it can be tweaked to use less heap memory. You should probably add that query to this question.

Comment: How could I see that query? I turned on the query log and also i have the debug.log but there's no info on the query there.